# Can I get the dask future and calculation status while calculating？

Tags: python, dask

I am using dask custom graph for calculation。I want to get a future while publishing the task graph, so that I can judge whether the calculation is complete by the state of the future.

When I was using client.get(graph,key), he returned a dask.dataframe, and it was delayed. Did not actually start the calculation

I can't get a future using client.get(), so I use client.compute(client.get(graph,key)) to get the future, however there is a problem that it is not real-time. I need to wait for 10-20s when calculating complex graphics. So are there other ways to achieve or improve?

If there is a better way, please let me know, thanks

```
>>> from dask.distributed import Client
    import dask.dataframe as dd

>>> def load_data_from_parquet(path, columns=None, filters=None):
        return dd.read_parquet(path=path, engine="pyarrow", columns=columns, filters=filters)

>>> client = Client()

>>> graph = {
        "x": (load_data_from_parquet,"/data/catalog/")
    }

>>> client.get(graph,"x")
Dask Name: read-parquet, 4 tasks

>>> future = client.compute(client.get(graph,"x"))
    future
Future: finalize status: pending, key: finalize-ef17005af921fa60e560123b4ac704c5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a combination of `persist` and `futures_of`

```py
In [1]: from distributed import futures_of, Client, wait

In [2]: import dask

In [3]: c = Client()

In [4]: ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries()

In [5]: foo = ddf.groupby('name').x.sum()

In [7]: bar = foo.persist()

In [8]: futures_of(bar) #
Out[8]: [<Future: finished, type: pandas.Series, key: ('series-groupby-sum-agg-6e2ad3cb7149694d9f0945910a62dbe1', 0)>]
```